# From a C# Global Static Variable point of view, what is redux?

Tags: c#, redux, static

From Google Searches =>
Redux allows you to manage your app's state in a single place and keep changes in your app more predictable and traceable.

Isn't that what global static variables or even depency injections are for?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say much for the C# side as I'm coming from JavaScript Redux.

Generally, Redux is a global variable. But that variable is immutable, you cannot directly change it. Instead, you send events (called "action") to a global "dispatcher" - that then forwards that event to middleware and then to "reducers".
A reducer is a pure function that is essentially a set of rules that calculates a new state value out of the old state and the action.

That way you have a traceable and predictable data flow - everything goes through the dispatcher and state changes only happen through rules in the reducers.

Then, in React/JavaScript, you have ways of subscribing to state changes so the UI updates - I would assume you have similar subscriptions or databindings in C#, but I don't really know.

So yes, Redux is a global variable - but one that can only be changed through events.